# How to add a character string as a code to ggplot object

Tags: r, string, ggplot2

A part of my code for ggplot is stored in a character vector. I would like to use this code as an additional geoms for my ggplot.

Example1:

```
  DF=data.frame(x=seq(1:10), y=seq(1:20))
   a='geom_line()'# This is a string that should be converted to RCode
```

So far I tried:

```
ggplot(DF, aes(x,y))+geom_point()+a
Error: Don't know how to add a to a plot

ggplot(DF, aes(x,y))+geom_point()+as.name(a)
Error: Don't know how to add as.name(a) to a plot

ggplot(DF, aes(x,y))+geom_point()+eval(parse(text=a))
Error in geom_line() + geom_line(y = 1) : 
non-numeric argument to binary operator

ggplot(DF, aes(x,y))+geom_point()+deparse(substitute(a))
Error: Don't know how to add deparse(substitute(a)) to a plot
```

Example 2:

```
DF=data.frame(x=seq(1:10), y=seq(1:20))
a='geom_line()+geom_line(y=1)'
```

Probable you are wondering, why I would like to do that in a first place? In a for loop, I created expressions and stored them in a list as characters. Later, I pasted together all expressions into a single string expression. Now, I would like to add this string to a ggplot command. Any suggestions?

Edit: Example 1 was successfully solved. But Example 2 stays unsolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `parse` function has text argument you need to pass `a` to. Try:

`ggplot(DF, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + eval(parse(text = a))`

More info here:
http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html#parsing-and-deparsing

In case of multiple statements, it is possible to deparse the original expression, add the new and then evaluate as a whole

```
original <- deparse(quote(ggplot(DF, aes(x,y)) + geom_point()))
new_call <- paste(original, '+', a)
eval(parse(text = new_call))
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, and I tried also with the text argument before, but for my original example did not work. When there are two geoms (e.g. `a='geom_line()+geom_line(y=1)'`) in a string, `eval(parse(text=a))` do not work. I will update my question with two geom arguments.

Comment: Don't edit the question directly please. Add it as an extra problem below the original one. The solution I put in is not actually solving the problem you now have :)

Comment: I think the problem is that the eval is trying to sum the parameters before adding it as an expression. A functional solution seems to deparse the original call, add the expression and then evaluate it as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a function to define these code into a list. Please see: [https://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~luke/classes/STAT4580/dry.html](https://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/%7Eluke/classes/STAT4580/dry.html)

Here I cited the related code:

> Defining a theme_slopegraph function to do the theme adjustment allows
> the adjustments to be easily reused:

```
theme_slopechart = function(toplabels = TRUE) {
     thm <- theme(...)
list(thm, ...) # add multiple codes
#...
}

p <- basic_barley_slopes ## from twonum.R
p + theme_slopechart()
```